# Python Operator precedence - 2 ** 3 ** 2 ** 1 = 512 - Not sure how?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python. Can someone please explain why 2 ** 3 ** 2 ** 1 is evaluated to 512. I understand about PEMDAS and left to right processing here, but couldn't figure out the reason for this output. Thanks much.

Comment: The statement turns out to be 2^9

Comment: Think about how you would calculate 2^3^2^1 in real life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python operators usually evaluate left to right, except for the exponentiation operator:

> Operators in the same box group left to right (except for
>   exponentiation, which groups from **right to left**).

[Source](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Thus,

```
 2 ** 3 ** 2 ** 1
```

is the same as

```
 2 ** (3 ** (2 ** 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a Python developer myself, so other people can correct me if I'm wrong, but I'd venture to guess this is how it's getting parsed:

```
2 ** (3 ** (2 ** 1))

= 2 ** (3 ** 2)
= 2 ** 9
= 512
```